# How to reshape a flat array into a 2d in C?

Tags: c

I have an array with x * x elements defined as a pointer.

I wanted to do something like this:

```
void func(const unsigned int x, const int *flat_array)
{
    const int (*reshaped)[x] = flat_array;
    ...
}
```

but how?

Comment: what does it mean `reshape`?

Comment: @DavideSpataro, reshape a flat array of x*x element to a 2d array with [x] by [x] elementes

Comment: @PeterJ, reshape: Gives a new shape to an array without changing its data (numpy definition)

Comment: Give or take a cast, what you've got should work.  What's the problem?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, The message that appears is: the expression must have a constant value

Comment: Well, you do need a C11 (or C99) compiler, not a C89 compiler.  The only reason to get that message is that you are using a compiler without support for variable-length arrays, which were added as a mandatory feature of C99 and were made into an optional feature in C11.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code works for me.  Note that it uses a C99 (and C11) *variable length array* (VLA).  It won't compile with a C89/C90 compiler.

```
#include <stdio.h>

static void func(const unsigned int x, const int *flat_array)
{
    const int (*reshaped)[x] = (void *)flat_array;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < x; i++)
    {
        for (unsigned int j = 0; j < x; j++)
            printf("%3d", reshaped[i][j]);
        putchar('\n');
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    int flat[] =
    {
        /* random -n 25 10 99 | commalist -n 5 -b '        ' */
        73, 34, 76, 48, 17,
        25, 71, 11, 87, 74,
        18, 87, 11, 47, 32,
        33, 62, 41, 55, 90,
        90, 28, 69, 58, 29,
    };

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        printf("R[%d]", i);
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
            printf(" [%d] = %2d", j, flat[i * 5 + j]);
        putchar('\n');
    }

    func(5, flat);
    return 0;
}
```

Compiled without warnings on a Mac running macOS Sierra 10.12.6 using GCC 7.1.0 with the compilation options:

```
$ gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wmissing-prototypes \
      -Wstrict-prototypes rs37.c -o rs37
$
```

Without the cast (to `void *`) in the function, I get the error:

```
initialization from incompatible pointer type [-Werror=incompatible-pointer-types]
```

The `void *` cast is an effective way to deal with the problem — but it could be misused very easily.  You could also write:

```
    const int (*reshaped)[x] = (int (*)[x])flat_array;
```

That explicitly casts direct to the correct type — pointer to array of integers of row width `x`.  You could add a `const` into the cast if you wanted to.

Output:

```
R[0] [0] = 73 [1] = 34 [2] = 76 [3] = 48 [4] = 17
R[1] [0] = 25 [1] = 71 [2] = 11 [3] = 87 [4] = 74
R[2] [0] = 18 [1] = 87 [2] = 11 [3] = 47 [4] = 32
R[3] [0] = 33 [1] = 62 [2] = 41 [3] = 55 [4] = 90
R[4] [0] = 90 [1] = 28 [2] = 69 [3] = 58 [4] = 29
 73 34 76 48 17
 25 71 11 87 74
 18 87 11 47 32
 33 62 41 55 90
 90 28 69 58 29
```

Comment: What's commalist?

Comment: @DavideSpataro: `commalist` is a moderately complex shell script wrapping an awk script that generates a list of comma-separated values from its input.  Currently 165 lines of shell (including moderately copious comments), of which about 50 lines is Awk.  The options say "print 5 values per line of output, and start each line with 8 blanks".  Shout if you're interested — see my profile.  (The `random` program is also my own homebrew.  It's not quite as polished as I'd like, though for generating 25 numbers between 10 and 99, it's perfectly clean.)

Answer (score 0):

this should do it :

```
int m,n;
typedef int myarray_t[x][x];
myarray_t *myarray;
myarray = (myarray_t *) flat_array;

for (m=0;m<x;m++)
   for (n=0;n<x;n++)
       printf("[%d][%d] : %d\n",m,n,(*myarray)[m][n]);
```

Answer (score 0):

if original was malloced and I understand what reshape means

```
#define MIN(x,y) ((x) > (y) ? (y) : (x))

int *reshape(int *src, int srcRows, int srcCols, int newRows, int newColums)
{
    int *newarray = (*src != NULL && newRows > 0 && newColums > 0) ? malloc(newRows * newColums) : NULL;

    if (newarray != NULL)
    {
        for (int row = 0; row < MIN(srcRows, newRows); row++)
            for (int col = 0; col < MIN(srcCols, newColums); col++)
                *(newarray + row * newColums + col) = *(src + row * srcCols + col);
        free(src);
    }
    return newarray;
}
```

If new array is smaller some data will be lost.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the pointer does point at an array, that is - a chunk of adjacent items of the same type, then you can safely cast the pointer type:

```
const int (*reshaped)[x] = (const int(*)[x])flat_array;
```

This is guaranteed to work because the type aliasing rules in C are only concerned of the nature of the pointed-at data and not so much about the pointer types involved. (See the concept of *effective type*, 6.5/6).